# \@clubpenalty leaks out

Tags: page-breaking, latex-base, widows-orphans

In the following example the value of `\clubpenalty` has been reset to the one of `\@clubpenalty` on the second page:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\subsection{abc}

blblb 

\clubpenalty=10000
\showthe\clubpenalty 
\lipsum
\showthe\clubpenalty 
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug? Can it be avoided? (I explictly wanted to set the larger \clubpenalty only for a small part of the document).

Comment: I’m in a hurry and I can only give you a quick hint: insert `\showthe\clubpenalty \showthe\everypar` *before* `\clubpenalty=10000`; then have a look to `ltsect.dtx`.

Comment: The polluted `\everypar` is dangling from `\subsection` -> `\@startsection` -> `\@ssect` -> `\@xsect` -> `\@afterheading`.

Comment: You can locally fix it by adding a second paragraph after `blblb`.  I'm not sure how to fix it globally, though.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you can fix it globally, because you don't want to have a single line of a paragraph after a section heading and then a page break.  So at the *first* `\par` after the heading you have to set `\clubpenalty=10000` to prevent shipout from mangling your paragraph.  You can then reset `\clubpenalty` only at the *second* `\par` after the section heading.  Bottomlined you can either have two paragraphs after the section heading or you have `{\everypar={}\clubpenalty=10000 ...}`.

Comment: It also appears to me as if `\clubpenalty` is meant to be set globally in the LaTeX format, because the value of `\@clubpenalty` is set to `\clubpenalty` *only once*, namely in `\begin{document}`.  In every other instance where `\clubpenalty` is “restored” it is merely set to the value saved from before (by default 150).  So any change to `\clubpenalty` in the document will be overwritten eventually (I noticed other occurences in `\@item` and `\end{...}` where you at least might be lucky due to protection by scoping).

Comment: I suspect this is STATUS BYDESIGN: the comment in `ltfiles.dtx` reads 'This stores the current normal (non-infinite) value of `\clubpenalty`; it should therefore be reset whenever the normal value is changed (as in the bibliography in the standard styles).'

Comment: @HenriMenke: well other penalties can be changed in the document without problems. So I don't think that it isn't meant to do. But I see the technical difficulties, but still wonder if the sectioning commands couldn't try harder, e.g by using 10002 instead of 10000 and testing for it in \@afterheading and other places.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course one could try harder, but even with saving and restoring `\clubpenalty` properly you couldn't circumvent the fact that you need two paragraphs after a section heading before `\clubpenalty` is reset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to avoid page breaks between a section title and the following text, LaTeX sets some parameter temporarily. It also sets `\clubpenalty` to 10000 in the paragraph following the section title; this is done via `\everypar`, which will contain something similar to

```
\clubpenalty10000 \everypar{\clubpenalty=\@clubpenalty \everypar{}}
```

so that at the *next* paragraph (the second one after the title), the value is restored to the standard one.

So what you need to temporarily change `\clubpenalty` to 9000 is

```
\@clubpenalty=9000
\clubpenalty=\@clubpenalty
```

that is, you need to set *both* parameters to the desired value.

The setting `\clubpenalty=\@clubpenalty` is done at begin document to start up with the desired value. You can never rely on `\clubpenalty` alone, because it *may* change during typesetting.

An example: the `babel-italian` module sets the club penalty to 3000; it does so with

```
\addto\extrasitalian{%
  \babel@savevariable\clubpenalty
  \babel@savevariable\widowpenalty
  \babel@savevariable\@clubpenalty
  \clubpenalty3000\widowpenalty3000\@clubpenalty\clubpenalty}%
```

so the values are saved when the language changes in order to be restored at the next language change. Note that both `\clubpenalty` and `\@clubpenalty` are saved.

Comment: Sounds as if latex needs something like `\setclubpenalty` which takes care of the details -- and I hope I remember the last bit when I sit over some italian text bit and wonder why it has has widow and club lines.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Blame David and the rest of the team. `;-)` Italian text should have *less* widows and club lines, at least in the intentions of Claudio Beccari who wrote the code and fixed it when I made him notice he didn't set `\@clubpenalty`, but only `\clubpenalty` (which is why I remember about the business).

Comment: I only know about Italian Widows from [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/apmdv.jpg)